# Gibbs Sampler for Normal and Inverse Gamma Distribution in R

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I'm trying to implement a Gibbs sampler for the following conditional distributions using R:

[image]

This is the code I have in R so far:

```
gibbs = function(N, v0, alpha, beta){

# Data
X = c(x1,...,xn);

# Parameters
n = length(X);
xbar = mean(X);
sigma2 = var(X);

# Starting values
mu0 = v0[1];
sigma20 = v0[2];
out = NULL;

for (i in 1:N){
  mu0 = rnorm(1, mean = ((n*xbar/sigma2 + mu0/sigma20) / (n/sigma2) + (1/sigma20)), sd = n/sigma2 + (1/sigma20)^-1);
  sigma20 = rinvgamma(1, n + alpha, 0.5*(sum(X - mu0))^2 + beta);
  out = rbind(out, c(mu0, sigma20)) 
}

return(out)

}
```

When I run the function using gibbs(1000, v0 = c(1,1), 0.001, 0.01), the code runs for 5 or so iterations before starting to output NaN for everything.

I'm new to R, and to MCMC methods, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The code does not implement the given formulas, see the second argument of 'rnorm'.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several conceptual and R-coding errors:

1. $\mu_0$ and $\sigma_0$ are hyper-parameters for the prior, hence should not be modified along iterations
2. the conditionals in the Gibbs sampler are about the sampling model parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ which means updating `mu=rnorm(...` and `sigma2=rinvgamma(...` in the R code
3. there was a factor 2 missing in `n/2` in the shape of the `rinvgamma` call
4. The term `sum(X - mu0))^2` is doubly wrong as it should be `sum((X - mu)^2)`
5. the power `-1` is not correctly set in the standard deviation in the  `rnorm` call, it should be

   `(n/sigma2 + 1/sigma20)^(-1/2)`
6. the `rinvgamma` function in `MCMCpack` is parameterised in terms of scale and shape, not rate and shape, hence the second parameter is the inverse of what it should be:

   `sigma2 = rinvgamma(1, n/2 + alpha, 1/(0.5*sum((X - mu)^2) + beta))`

   which is the principal reason for the diverging chain in the original version.

The entire R code could thus be

```
gibbs = function(N, v0, alpha, beta){    
# parameters
n = length(X)
nxbar = sum(X)
sigma2 = var(X)
# hyperparameters
mu0 = v0[1]
sigma20 = v0[2]
out = NULL   
for (i in 1:N){
  mu = rnorm(1, 
    mean = (nxbar/sigma2 + mu0/sigma20) / (n/sigma2) + (1/sigma20), 
    sd = 1/sqrt(n/sigma2 + 1/sigma20))
  sigma2 = rinvgamma(1, n/2 + alpha, 1/(sum((X - mu)^2)/2 + beta))
  out = rbind(out, c(mu, sigma2)) # yuk!!
}
return(out)}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for picking those out! Quick question: regarding the hyper-parameters, should I specify these based on the data? e.g. μ = mean(X)

Comment: This is not an issue with the MCMC but with the Bayesian analysis. On principle the prior hyperparameters should not depend on the data.

Comment: That did the trick - thank you again!!

Comment: Note that `rnorm` comes from the **stats** rpackage which is a base package and can be thought of as part of R. The inverse gamma distribution does not exist yet in **stats** and to has to  be taken from another R package. There are some differences across packages in the parameterizations  for this distribution so it could help to mention the package used.

Comment: It's worth noting that `out = rbind(out, c(mu, sigma2))` is an example of "growing objects", a very inefficient way to store MCMC iterations, see [the R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#page=13) for details.

Comment: @alanocallaghan:  thank you for mentioning the [R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#page=13) book, it is a great collection of horror stories.

Answer (score 0):

According to Gibbs sampler, we always start with proposed value  as
$\mu_0$ , $\sigma_0$ and update those values as $\mu_1$ , $\sigma_1$ by drawing from conditional distributions. So, I think within for loop in left $\mu_0$ should be replaced by $\mu[i]$ and after equal sign $\mu[i-1]$ and same for $\sigma$.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).